# Nuxt add assets javascript files

Tags: javascript, webpack, nuxt.js

I have started a small project using **Nuxt** **Js** and i imported my **CSS** files correctly.
i would like to know how can i load and bundle **Js** files too.

I have already tried to add the following code in my nuxt.config.js but it doesn't works :

```
  script: [
    { src: '@/plugins/test.js' }
 ],
```

also i tried this following code :

```
vendor: ['@/plugins/test.js'],
```

is there any suggestions  to fix that please ? 
thanks

Comment: Have you tried `plugins: [  '~/plugins/test.js'' ]` ?

Comment: @Jainil already tried without any result :(